# Format date from php mysql query datetime datatype

Tags: php

I have a php mysql query for a datetime. The result from the query is:

```
2017-09-04 11:58:26
```

I use the below and it appears the time is wrong.

```
$date_time = new DateTime($row['act_date_long']);
$date_time->format('D n/j/Y g:s a')
```

The result I get is:

```
Mon 9/4/2017 11:26 am
```

I need the result to be

```
Mon 9/4/2017 11:58 pm
```

What is causing the time difference and how do I format the datetime to my desired format? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to check timezone?

Comment: 11:00 *is* AM if you don’t give any more information. You need to either store the time in 24 hour format, or store AM/PM too.

Comment: `$date_time->format('D n/j/Y g:i a');` it should be `i`(for minute) instead of `s`(for second)

Comment: Your time 2017-09-04 11:58:26 is in 24hr format. Then how could you make 11:58:26 as PM? If it was 23:58:26 it will be PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for time is incorrect, your printing `g:s` which is hours and seconds.

Should be

```
$date_time->format('D n/j/Y g:i a');
```